# Can we import a module by tracing it which is not in sys.path, instead it is in some child folder of my CWD

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have seen this, but when I tried it did not work,
I have one folder 'childFolder' in my current working directory, and inside that I have the module moduleName.py.

```
    import cwd.childFolder.moduleName as mod
    mod.someclass().method()
```

Comment: oh, got it. :) we need to make the childFolder a package.